# My mapboxgl doesn't load vector tile maps published by geoserver properly

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Why when I load the Vector tile map of geoserver, the console shows that the pbf file has been successfully requested, but I always don't see the display of the map in the map, I can make sure that it is not the reason for the vector map, because the display can be loaded successfully in the leaflet.

```
                map.addSource('vector-tile-source', {
                    type: 'vector',
                    tiles: [
                        'http://localhost:9999/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/zhouweijun%3Aps_line_3857@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
                    ],
                    scheme: "tms",
                    minzoom: 2,
                    maxzoom: 20
                });

                map.addLayer({
                    id: 'vector-tile-layer',
                    type: 'line',
                    source: 'vector-tile-source',
                    'source-layer': 'layer-name',
                    paint: {
                        'line-color': '#ff0000',
                        'line-width': 2
                    }
                });
```

The display can be loaded successfully in the leaflet

Comment: Same issue here. Did you solve this?